# zlib_decode() data error

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been struggling to install/configure Composer for about 3 days, and I'm totally lost:

I type `composer install` and it produced:

[image]

After I type `composer diagnose` & reading a lot of articles without knowing exactly what I'm reading about, I conclude that this is because of my network connection behinds the `proxy`. If it's so how could I just force installing it behind of proxy connection of my network (mobile network).

Comment: @all, it's solved already I changed my network provider .. and everything is ok